# Can you have Radio Buttons that are not beside each other but still work in one radio group?

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

What I want to do is have several radio buttons all on a different picture so when you click on that radio button it becomes the Back Ground, If I put the radio buttons in a Radio Group all of the buttons go right beside each other, But I need them basically on the four edges of the page. I have my layout in Relative layout but when I move a radio button it leaves the radio group is there anyway to stop this? Thanks Michael.

This is the code for the radio groups

```
 <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/PictureSelection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Picture1" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/EditQuestion2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Picture1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Picture2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Picture2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/EditQuestion1" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a button to a radio group does nothing more than tell the machine that all the buttons are "answers" to the same "question."  In other words they are all possible selections for ONE option. You could have buttons all over the page, if they were grouped you could never have more than one of them selected.  If you had two button groups only one button from each group could be "on" (selected) at a time so you would have two buttons total active, etc.  Grouping buttons has nothing to do with positioning.

Changing the position of a radio button does nothing that should affect whether the radio button is grouped, make sure that you declare all your buttons before you declare the radio button group and that you add each button to the group AFTER the group is declared.

Comment: Thanks for the accept.  To be clear you CAN declare and then add buttons to a group after the group has been declared.  However, I find it easier to keep track of if I declare all the buttons, declare the group, then add the buttons to the group.

Answer (score 0):

The positions of the buttons do not matter. As long as they are in the same group. It is possible that when you "move" it you may be accidentally making a new button and adding it to that location? You would have to give some more info on this problem to get a clear answer, such as some code.

Comment: oh... Instead of using an XML layout, try to add them programatically. I was thinking about the swing radio buttons and button groups. I don't know if that is possible in android but you should be able to.